# Can I upgrade my MacBookPro Model6.1 8GB (2x 4GB) to 16GB (2x 8GB)

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, upgrade, memory

I have a MacBook Pro mid 2010 Model 6.1 i7 17" with 8GB RAM inside. I want to upgrade to 16GB. I have seen that it should be possible on the model 7.1 but I have 6.1 Can I upgrade? Does it work on my MacBookPro?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I upgrade my MacBook mid 2010 to 16GB of RAM? (2x8G)](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/42426/can-i-upgrade-my-macbook-mid-2010-to-16gb-of-ram-2x8g)

Comment: Not a duplicate. The Mid 2010 MacBook and Mid 2010 MacBook Pro have different maximum amounts of RAM.

Answer (score 1):

[Apple's specs](http://support.apple.com/kb/SP581?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) for the Mid 2010 17" MacBook Pro state the maximum is 8GB.

[OWC](http://eshop.macsales.com/memory/maxram) maintains a list of Macs that can accept more RAM than Apple's official numbers. Unfortunately the Mid 2010 MBP is not on that list. (Do not confuse it with the Mid 2010 13" MacBook.)

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple tech specs, you can't upgrade to 16GB.

> 4GB (two 2GB SO-DIMMs) of 1066MHz DDR3 memory; two SO-DIMM slots support up to 8GB

[MacBook Pro (17-inch, Mid 2010) - Technical Specifications](http://support.apple.com/kb/SP581)

Comment: No...[6,1 was Mid 2010](http://eshop.macsales.com/shop/Apple_Upgrade_Guide/Model_ID_MacBookPro_MacBook). There was no "Late 2009" Pro and you linked to _Mid_ 2009, which is 5,3 to 5,5.

Comment: You are right. I update my answer with the right link. The answer is the same. You can't do it.