# MBP 13' (mid-2010; 7,1) 2.4 Core 2 Duo P8600 supporting 16 GB RAM under Win7?

Tags: macbook-pro, windows, memory

I’ve got a **MBP 13′ (mid-2010) 2.4 Core 2 Duo** (full specs below) that I’m now operating **solely under Win7 64Bit**. It formerly run as well under OS X 10.**6.8**, relatively to which the firmware seems up to date (MBP71.0039.B0**B**).

Would my system recognize 16 GB RAM **if operated under Win7 64 Bit?** Or would it require the latest firmware (MBP71.0039.B0**E**) of OS-X 10.**7.5** (which was never installed on my MBP) anyway?

As far as I have read elsewhere, using 16 GB RAM under OS X seems to definitely require this later version of OS X (including the respective firmware update); so I'd like to know whether this is an issue of OS X or (as I suspect) the firmware.

- Modellname: MacBook Pro
- Modell-Identifizierung: MacBookPro7,1
- Prozessortyp: Intel Core 2 Duo
- Prozessorgeschwindigkeit: 2,4 GHz
- Anzahl der Prozessoren: 1
- Gesamtzahl der Kerne: 2
- L2-Cache: 3 MB
- Speicher: 4 GB
- Busgeschwindigkeit: 1,07 GHz
- Boot-ROM-Version: MBP71.0039.B0B
- SMC-Version (System): 1.62f6

Answer (score 1):

According to Apple your MacBook Pro only supports 8 GB RAM, however [Mactracker](http://mactracker.ca) says it will support 16 GB.

Also at [MacSales.com](https://www.macsales.com) have a look at [Upgrades for MacBook and MacBook Pro 'Unibody' Models 2008 – 2010](https://eshop.macsales.com/shop/memory/Apple_MacBook_MacBook_Pro/Upgrade/DDR3) and [16.0GB OWC Memory Upgrade Kit](https://eshop.macsales.com/item/OWC/8566DDR3S16P/) show your model MBP supporting 16 GB RAM. Or at Crucial, see: [Apple MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2010) compatible upgrades](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/compatible-upgrade-for/Apple/macbook-pro-%2813-inch%2C-mid-2010%29)

[image: 16 GB OWC Memory Upgrade Kit]

Answer (score 0):

Your particular MacBook Pro can, per [EveryMac.com](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-2-duo-2.66-aluminum-13-mid-2010-unibody-specs.html), support up to 16GB of RAM.

[image]

As noted in the specs, it would need to be updated ***past*** 10.7.5 to obtain the latest EFI updates so that it would recognize the 16GB.  So, prior to installing the memory, you should install a newer OS Mavericks, Yosemite, etc. should be fine.

**Based on your question about the firmware version, according to [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201518), you have the latest version; so your system should be able to address the full 16GB**

[image]

As for the memory, I have personally installed a Crucial 16GB PC3-8500 kit in my mid-2010 MacBook Pro with zero issues.  My preference is to use branded memory with lifetime warranties; no company is perfect and there will be failures, but I want to know that I am supported for the long haul.

Comment: Thanks! But my firmware version is not this latest one (MBP71.0039.B0B -  "B" instead of "E"), and I did not get an update suggestion since my latest version of OS-X had been 10.6.8 and not 10.7.5 ff. As I said, at current, my MBP only runs under Win7 64Bit, i. e., I removed OS-X from my machine.

Comment: ... so the big question is whether my firmware would prevent me from using 16GB RAM under Win7 as well, or whether this restriction is due to a driver issue

Comment: .. so the big question is whether my firmware would prevent me from using 16GB RAM under Win7 as well, or whether this restriction is due to to an issue pertaining to OS-X rather than the firmware, and would thus not show up under Win7.

Comment: Why would it not show up in Windows 7?

Comment: I'm not _claiming_ that the issue wouldn't show up under Win7, but I'm just trying to figure out whether there might be a chance that this is so. There have been related prior postings that indicate that this might indeed be an issue pertaining to OS-X rather than the firmware - e. g, see [link](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/42426/can-i-upgrade-my-macbook-mid-2010-to-16gb-of-ram-2x8g): one answer says "If you load Windows 7 onto the MacBook Pro (2010 i5 or i7) with 16GB RAM loaded, Windows 7 will boot OK and be able to see/address the 16GB RAM.".

Comment: There wouldn't be an issue.  A Mac is (don't let Apple folks hear this) nothing more than a fancy PC.  If the EFI/BIOS can see 16GB, providing you are using a 64bit OS, your OS  will address all 16GB.

Comment: Thanks - now we are at the point! Do I have to upgrade to EFI/BIOS MBP71.0039.B0*E* or would MBP71.0039.B0*B* (currently running on my MBP) be sufficient to use 16GB RAM *under* *Win7*? Your answer seems to indicate that I would definitely have to upgrade to MBP71.0039.B0*E* since it is presumably an EFI/BIOS issue?!

Comment: In the support page I provided, it lists the latest firmware.  Is that the one that gives you the ability to see 16GB specifically?  I don't know, but you do need the firmware that was included with the 10.7.5 release of OS X.  If you install the firmware linked, you will have the necessary firmware to use 16GB