# What is the correct RAM for a 2010 MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, memory, motherboard

I bought a 2.4GHz mid 2010 MacBook Pro logicboard on eBay. Upon installing RAM, the computer beeps every five seconds indicating it doesn't detect RAM. I used standard 8500s 1066MHZ RAM with 8 modules on each side of the chip (2Rx4?). The seller claims the board will only work with RAM that has 4 modules on each side of the chip (1Rx4?). I guess the terminology here would be 1Rx4?

The RAM is good because both chips worked in an A1342 MacBook.

I understand Macs are particularly sensitive to RAM clock speeds and such but I'm concerned I bought a bad board. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: See this answer about firmware to address the full 16GB:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/257989/119271

Comment: @Allan Thanks. I actually have 2x2GB (I should have noted this in the question). I see the RAM linked in that answer is the 1Rx4 configuration. I bought a 1GB 8500S 1066MHZ 1Rx4 to test the board. The module should arrive in a few days and then I'll know for sure.

Comment: @Allan Lol, seller refunded because it was lost in the mail. I guess I'll have to find something else to test. I'll try the local computer shop and ask to quickly pop in a SODIMM to test it.

Answer (score 2):

According to the free app **MacTracker**, a mid-2010 Macbook Pro has:  Memory Slots 2 - 204-pin PC3-8500 (1066 MHz) DDR3 SO-DIMM. And has a maximum memory of 8 Gigs. I've read that Macs are sensitive to memory chips too. So I'd make sure the numbers above were followed. I upgraded my iMac with chips from Crucial. Works fine.

Comment: I installed 2x2GB 8500S 1066MHZ Hynix DDR3 chips. Didn't work. I'm going to order the chip the seller claimed would work. I might stop at the computer shop and ask if I can quickly pop in a SODIMM to test.

Comment: good idea about testing it.